# Printing to screen VGA variable offset

Tags: assembly, vga, as86

I'm trying to display characters on screen by calling the following function in my C code:

```
.global _putInMemory

;void putInMemory (int segment, int address, char character)
    _putInMemory:
        mov bp,sp
        push ds
        mov ax,[bp+2]
        mov si,[bp+4]
        mov cl,[bp+6]
        mov ds,ax
        mov [si],cl
        pop ds
        ret
```

like this:

```
    int segment_start = 0xB000;
    putInMemory(segment_start, 0x8140, 'R');
    putInMemory(segment_start, 0x8141, 0x1F);
    putInMemory(segment_start, 0x8142, 'A');
    putInMemory(segment_start, 0x8143, 0x1F);
```

However, this only displays the first letter without the color, but when I specify this in the code like this, it works just fine:

```
putInMemory(0xB000, 0x8140, 'R');
putInMemory(0xB000, 0x8141, 0x1F);
putInMemory(0xB000, 0x8142, 'A');
putInMemory(0xB000, 0x8143, 0x1F);
```

I don't understand why it does not work if I store int in a variable. Is `int` too small?
I'm using the `bcc` compiler

**Edit:**
The correct code would be this:

```
;void putInMemory (int segment, int address, char character)
_putInMemory:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    push ds
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    mov si,[bp+6]
    mov cl,[bp+8]
    mov ds,ax
    mov [si],cl
    pop ds
    pop bp
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you know and follow the calling convention `bcc` uses. Typical compilers will expect the `bp` and `si` registers (among others) to be preserved across function calls. The compiler may be using `bp` to address your `segment_start` local variable, but you destroy `bp` so on the second function call some garbage will be passed instead, producing the observed behavior.

Try saving and restoring `bp` and `si` (just like you do with `ds`) to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: i tried pushing `bp`, `si` and `ds` to the stack and retrieving them by poping them off at the end of the function in reverse order, but this did not seem to fix it

Comment: Try saving all registers then (conveniently using `pusha`/`popa`) - the compiler may be using any of the caller-saved registers to hold the `segment_start` variable.